# Unable to fetch fatal: protocol error: bad line length 2

Tags: git, github

I have a Windows desktop PC on which I am currently teaching myself Python in Atom. When I wanted to access my Python-files with my laptop, I searched in the internet for a solution and came across Git and Github. Creating the remote repository worked well and I was able to access it with my Linux laptop. However, when I made changes on my Windows PC and pushed them to the remote repository on Github, I tried to use the fetch button on my laptop to access those changes there, but the error message "Unable to fetch

fatal: protocol error: bad line length 2" showed up in Atom.
Could you help me fixing this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol that Git uses prefixes each line or other data packet with a four-byte hex length of the length and packet together.  In this case, the message means that something is modifying the stream to make it invalid, since `0002` is not a valid packet header in your version.

Usually this happens because you're on Windows, you're using HTTPS, and you have some sort of third-party antivirus or firewall that intercepts all TLS connections, which may or may not include tampering with them, in order to "protect you from malware".  Usually this software makes things less secure and it very frequently breaks Git, so the best approach is to uninstall that third-party antivirus or firewall and use Windows Defender and Windows Firewall.  This can also happen if you're using some other sort of proxy or TLS MITM device, in which case you should either not use it or report the fact that it's broken to your network administrator.

You could also try using SSH instead, as usually these programs don't support intercepting SSH connections.

Comment: I am using Mac, and also seeing the same issue in atom.

Comment: The answer remains the same.  Something is tampering with your connection.  Remove that thing, and things should work.

Comment: I think it might be a problem in the Github plugin of Atom, because everything works for me in the Linux terminal, but not in Atom. I checked to see if an anti virus program was enabled on any of the computers, but no such software was used anywhere. That is why this solution didn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

MAC OSX/Atom when clicking on the git addin fetch button to update your branches.

On OSX 12.6/Atom 1.60 I searched for the issue specific to Atom, I found this https://github.com/atom/github/issues/2720#issuecomment-1295898268 which fixed my issue, basically swapping out the git binary.

May give a pointer to solve for Windows/Atom.

```
mv /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/dugite/git/bin/git /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/dugite/git/bin/git.original
mv /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/dugite/git/libexec/git-core/git /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/dugite/git/libexec/git-core/git.original

ln -s /usr/bin/git /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/dugite/git/libexec/git-core/git
ln -s /usr/bin/git /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/node_modules/dugite/git/bin/git
```